# Can't Insert or Delete from my WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF DataGrid that I want to be able to Update, Insert and Delete from. I bind to the DataGrid.DataContext with an ObservableCollection.

When the DataGrid's SelectionChanged() event fires, I perform a Context.SaveChanges() to write back to the database.

However, the above only works when I Update existing records. When I try to add a new record by clicking on the last row in the DG or when I press delete, the SaveChanges() doesn't do anything. The data is not added or deleted.

How can I add or delete records from a DataGrid? Here is my DG xaml:

```
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,12,0,89" Name="grdContact" 
                          CanUserAddRows="True" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="False"     CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                          Focusable="True"
                          SelectionChanged="grdContact_SelectionChanged"

            <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Width="150" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Width="150" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My Code Behind - Pseudo code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            var CustomerObj = new ObservableCollection<Contact>(GetContacts());
            grdContact.DataContext = CustomerObj;
}

    private void grdContact_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: You might also consider [binding directly to an `EntityCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738469.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375.aspx) does not notify the context of added or removed items. In fact, it knows nothing about your database context!

You'll have to wire up the `CustomerObj` collection to add or delete objects from the context:

```
CustomerObj.CollectionChanged += CustomerObj_CollectionChanged;
...

private void CustomerObj_CollectionChanged(object sender,
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems.Cast<Contact>())
                Context.AddObject(item);
            break;
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems.Cast<Contact>())
                Context.DeleteObject(item);
            break;
        // handle Replace, Move, Reset
    }

    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem.
When getContacts() returned List I was able only to update (not insert or delete).
But when getContects returns IQueryable Everything works perfect (but I can't sort :( )